# Setting up a windows VM in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

My company is evaluating cloud foundry as a PaSS solution. This morning I was watching the “Why we picked CF as the Basis for our Public Cloud Multi-Tenant Platform” presentation on cfsummit.com. During the presentation they showed an [image: image of their environment]. The image showed that they split there CF environment into 3 sections, warden container, Bosh managed VM’s and other VM’s. In other VM’s they had a windows VM. My understanding was the CF VM’s had to be Ubuntu. Can you setup windows VMs in Cloud Foundry?

The presentation can be found http://www.cfsummit.com/sites/cfs2015/files/pages/files/cfsummit15_jeroen.pdf. The image is on slide 5.

As always thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The next major release of Cloud Foundry, code named Diego, will support the deployment of containers that use operating systems other than the default Ubuntu.

Out of the box, Diego will support containers running Windows Server 2012 as the underlying operating system, and they will also support containers that can deploy and run Docker images.

There's a fantastic talk that describes this technology in detail here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSxI9eonBVs